# Git Extensions: Can I use a local .gitconfig in Git Extensions?

Tags: git-extensions

I want to use a included local .gitconfig which works in Git but not in Git Extensions. So in my local config I include (MyRepository/.git/config):

```
[include]
    path = ../.gitconfig
```

In my .gitconfig (MyRepository/.gitconfig) above I would like to insert e.g. a merge and a diff tool and hoped Git Extensions uses it. The entries in Git Extension settings are only synchronized with the config-file, not with the .gitconfig above. Does anyone know what I can do to let Git Extension consider the included .gitconfig above?

Comment: No, we don't support relative or included configs. Such questions are better asked at the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

you can select “local” in git settings

https://youtu.be/Xihy2qw0p-o
https://youtu.be/oacpBgyJzag